# SQLITE3 - Deleting rows that have multiple columns of the same value

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite3 database from which I want to remove rows that have two fields of the same value.
It seems that I am able to select such values with this query:
`SELECT * FROM mydb GROUP BY user_id, num HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

However I am not able to delete them.
`DELETE FROM mydb WHERE user_id IN (SELECT * FROM mydb GROUP BY user_id, num HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)` 

returns a syntax error.

This is what I expect:

Example:

```
id  user_id     num
1   1           1
2   1           1
3   2           1
4   1           2
5   2           2
```

In this example id 1 and 2 have both columns (user_id and num) of the same value so they should be removed. Preferably, but not necessarily I would like to have a solution that would leave only one such row (doesn't matter which one).

Result:

```
id  user_id     num
2   1           1
3   2           1
4   1           2
5   2           2
```

Note: id is a primary key. user_id is a foreign key. num is an INTEGER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were having a syntax error because your `IN` operator has a single value on the left (`user_id`) but a table of non-single-value rows in the right side (`SELECT *`). Compare like with like; `WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id ...)` to avoid it.

Anyway, here's a query to delete all-but-newest:

```
DELETE FROM mydb
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM mydb
  GROUP BY user_id, num
);
```

The subquery will return the highest `id` for every unique `(user_id, num)` combination. Then we just delete all the other rows. I.e. in your example, the subquery would return 2, 3, 4, 5 as "correct", which would result in deletion of row 1.